# Filtering SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to filter my SharePoint list to display last one year record but it's not working as expected. I am trying following but it's not working.

[image]

Alternatively, I thought to create two calculated fields one which keep the year of "RecordingEnd" date field and other one will keep Year[Today]-1 but today also not supported in calculated field.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems [Today]-365 will do the trick.